# how to fetch xls using google search appliance

Tags: excel, google-search-appliance

I have used google search appliance in my application to search files.
I am able to search all files .However, i am not able to fetch xls file.
Search url for for same is:

GoogleSearch.html?

`advanced=true&filter=0&requiredfields=&as_q=content&lr=&as_epq=&country=&as_eq=&unit=&committee=&sort=&function=&num=10&contenttype=&as_occt=any&as_filetype=xls&site=&Submit.x=91&Submit.y=15`

Comment: It works for me. Do you have any XLS files?

Comment: Ohh..is it?don't know why this is not working with my code..also, could you please advise if i can fetch only .html pages using such search url?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the "Index diagnostic" page on the GSA Admin Console to confirm that those .xls files are actually stored in the index.

Comment: yes...they are present on index page .Do you know how to fetch html files?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. They should be searchable by default. Use the "Test Center" in the GSA Admin Console to try your queries.